# How to integrate Paytm with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paytm

I want to integrate paytm payment gateway in codeigniter in my website and i have searched a lot, but i found only in PHP.I have tried with php library but while validating checksum it is not working.Can anyone suggest any library to integrate paytm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was searching for this same option today and finally had to tweak the library they provided [here](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_PHP).

1. Cloned their kit to a different folder
2. Moved the contents of the folder *lib* to *application/third_party/paytmlib*
3. In the moved path, Configured *config_paytmp.php* values according to my site set
4. From their kit path moved this file *TxnTest.php* to *views* folder and changed form post tag like below `<form method="post" action="paytmpost">`
5. Have added controller methods like below

   ```
   function paytm()
   {
     $this->load->view('TxnTest');
   }


   function paytmpost()
   {
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    // following files need to be included
    require_once(APPPATH . "/third_party/paytmlib/config_paytm.php");
    require_once(APPPATH . "/third_party/paytmlib/encdec_paytm.php");

    $checkSum = "";
    $paramList = array();

    $ORDER_ID = $_POST["ORDER_ID"];
    $CUST_ID = $_POST["CUST_ID"];
    $INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = $_POST["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"];
    $CHANNEL_ID = $_POST["CHANNEL_ID"];
    $TXN_AMOUNT = $_POST["TXN_AMOUNT"];

   // Create an array having all required parameters for creating checksum.
    $paramList["MID"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID;
    $paramList["ORDER_ID"] = $ORDER_ID;
    $paramList["CUST_ID"] = $CUST_ID;
    $paramList["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = $INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID;
    $paramList["CHANNEL_ID"] = $CHANNEL_ID;
    $paramList["TXN_AMOUNT"] = $TXN_AMOUNT;
    $paramList["WEBSITE"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE;

    /*
    $paramList["MSISDN"] = $MSISDN; //Mobile number of customer
    $paramList["EMAIL"] = $EMAIL; //Email ID of customer
    $paramList["VERIFIED_BY"] = "EMAIL"; //
    $paramList["IS_USER_VERIFIED"] = "YES"; //

    */

   //Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
    $checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);
    echo "<html>
   <head>
   <title>Merchant Check Out Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center>
           <form method='post' action='".PAYTM_TXN_URL."' name='f1'>
   <table border='1'>
    <tbody>";

    foreach($paramList as $name => $value) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name .'" value="' . $value .         '">';
    }

    echo "<input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUMHASH' value='". $checkSum . "'>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.f1.submit();
   </script>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>";
    }
   ```

Note : `paytmpost()` is modified from the `pgRedirect.php` in their kit. The `pgResponse.php` could also be tweaked to a controller function to process the output from the payment gateway.

Comment: this helps me to integrate paytm in my site. But when I click back button from payment page `(https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction)` , it just refreshing the page. Can I go back to previous page on click of back button

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. You can set the push state so that the back page would go back accordingly. I guess You might have done this by now.

Comment: @Rajesh  https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_PHP  this is not avalable can you please help on same

Comment: @MrCoder sorry, just seeing your message. That repository was from Paytm, I didn't fork it then. Please reach out to their support.